# First $_GET parameter dosn't work in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, get

I'm using .htaccess on my dashboard and I'm using it to short and organize my URL so for that i try to add some $_GET parameters in .htaccess file and when i checked for the output parameters i get the second , third and forth parameter but not the first one

This is URL **before** using htaccess :

http://example.com/dashboard?param1=first&param2=second&param3=third&param4=forth

This is URL **after** using htaccess :

http://example.com/dashboard/first/second/third/forth

The output from printing $_GET :

`array(4) { ["param1"]=> string(3) "php" ["param2"]=> string(6) "second" ["param3"]=> string(5) "third" ["param4"]=> string(5) "forth" }`

I don't know why is first parameter is getting 'php' as a value instead of getting the value from URL

This is my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ([^\.]+)/$ index.php?param1=$1
RewriteRule ([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2
RewriteRule ([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3
RewriteRule ([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4
```

Comment: Where is the location of your .htaccess? How do you call the first link when testing?

Comment: Do you mean .htaccess file ?
The file located in the main directory right beside index.php file
here is .htaccess file located :
http://example.com/dashboard/.htaccess